# Wordpress redirect to xampp's dashboard except homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

My system is MAC and I am running Xampp for mac.

I search for many solutions and I thought it must be because of my .htaccess missing file , that all my rest of the links in wordpress even my posts, page **except my homepage** redirects to localhost/dashboard which is xampp's dashboard.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is my .htaccess file , and I have all set

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

in apache `httpd.conf` file

Now what else I can do? I am stuck with this, Even when I click the permalink on my wp-admin page, it shows no object found, 404 error. The page exits, the post exists, everything exists and still I can see only homepage.

Answer (score 7):

Since WordPress seems to be located in /wordpress/, change `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]`?

Answer (score 0):

after hours of search I found that I need to give write permission for my root wordpress folder, hence it was achieved by

```
sudo chmod -R 777 wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this

```html
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your htaccess file. for local version, you need to declare your root folder on the last RewriteRule before the index.php for it to work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /rootfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```